# Installing Ubuntu from bootable flash drive leads right back to installation menu

Tags: usb, wubi, system-installation

I am new to installing Ubuntu, but I managed to install wubi before. This time I created a bootable usb stick to install Ubuntu from, as explained [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). I followed every step and used `D:/` as the USB flash drive.

When I restarted my laptop, the Ubuntu installation menu showed up, but I couldn't select the option:

```
Try "Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu".
```

When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, my machine just restarts and goes back to the Ubuntu installation menu.

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

Your have asked two questions:

1. How to install Ubuntu from a USB flash drive
2. How to restore Grub menu after a failed Ubuntu installation.

One by one

1. You have used a utility from [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/). I have not tested it so, I don't know how effectively it works. I suggest you to use [Livelinuxusb creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/). It is very fast and easy to use. You can use [UNenbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) too.
   As far as failed Ubuntu installation is concerned it may be due to hardware conflict. Try reseting `BIOS`. If problem persists please comment with full hardware description.
2. Boot from Windows Installation CD/DVD and do a `startup repair`. It will remove the grub startup menu and fix the issue. You can boot directly into Windows 7 afterwards.